# VB.NET read standard output

Tags: vb.net

From my application I need to run a command and parse the output. I can do this with no problem but I don't want the command to be displayed. I hoped `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` would work but it doesn't. Take the sample code below for example. It works fine but the command window still visibly opens and closes very quickly and I need it to never show its ugly face. How can I fix this?

```
Dim myprocess As New Process
Dim lines As String = ""

With myprocess
    .StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
    .StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ipconfig"
    .StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    .Start()
End With

lines = myprocess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd

MsgBox(lines)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `CreateNoWindow` to `True` too.

If what you are trying to achieve is to find the IP address(es) of the local machine, there are [more direct ways of doing it](http://www.csharp-examples.net/local-ip/).

Comment: @Sani Huttunen: Fixed it; thanks. "Negative" `bool` properties are always very confusing...

Comment: Thanks this works nicely. And no I'm not trying to get an IP address. I just used that as a quick example :)

Answer (score 1):

Include

```
.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings in tandem:

```
            .CreateNoWindow = True
            .UseShellExecute = False
```

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/09/28/createnowindow.aspx for more details.